# Catching SIGSEGV using signals and sigsegjmp/siglongjmp

Tags: c, signals, segmentation-fault

I am writing a little program to scan a single memory addy on each page of the memory to see if it is readable/or read-writable/or none.

NOTE: I have not shown parts of the code, because its the signal handeling that is causing the error.

This while loop for going through the addys

```
char * currAddy;
currAddy = (char*)0x00000000;

while(1){

    int readWrite = read_write(currAddy);

    printf("Chunk val returned %i\n", readWrite);

    if(currAddy == (char*)0xfffff000)
        break;

    currAddy += pageSize;

}
```

The rest for handling the signal

```
int read_write (char * currAddy)
{

myRead = 0;
myWrite = 0;

/*
 myRead = 0 & myWrite = 0 -> NOT A CHUNK -> RW = -1
 myRead = 0 & myWrite = 1 -> NOT POSSIBLE
 myRead = 1 & myWrite = 0 -> RW = 0
 myRead = 1 & myWrite = 1 -> RW = 1

 */

if (sigsetjmp(jumpbuf, 1) == 0){

    //try and read
    char test = *currAddy;
    myRead = 1;

    //try and write
    *currAddy = 'a';
    myWrite = 1;


}else{

    //SIGSEGV while reading
    if (myRead == 0)
        return -1;

    //SIGSEGV while writing
    if (myRead == 1 && myWrite == 0)
        return 0;

    printf("Inside setjmp\n");

}

printf("Below the sigjmp\n");
sleep(1);

//return 1 because we can both read and write to this position

//doesnt appear to run though -- HELP HERE?
return 1;

}
```

Here is where the signal is handled

```
void handler (int sig)
{
    siglongjmp(jumpbuf, 1);
}
```

Now when I run this the output looks like this:

```
Chunk val returned -1
Chunk val returned -1
Chunk val returned -1
Chunk val returned 0
Chunk val returned 0
Below the sigjmp
Inside setjmp
Below the sigjmp
Below the sigjmp
Inside setjmp
Below the sigjmp
Below the sigjmp
Inside setjmp
.........
```

Edited: I can't seem to figure out why it will never return the 1? Also it's weird how come it prints "Below the sigjmp" twice. Any helps/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `printf("Below the sigjmp\n");` will be printed if both reading and writing were successful.

Comment: Yes that is true, but then we would also see "Chunk val returned 1" after each "Below the sigjmp" if it was really returning to the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

per POSIX, you can't use (sig)longjump in a signal handler -- you get undefined behavior if you do.  At least some Unixes do allow it, however (BSD-derived ones generally), so what you'll see here depends on what OS you're running on.

It looks like you're getting a crash in the `sleep` call (perhaps due to corrupted signal/stack state from the earlier siglongjmp) which causes it to loop back to the `sigsetjmp`.

Its also possible that the successful `*currAddy = 'a';` is clobbering something important, causing a later crash that loops back to the `sigsetjmp`